# Changing the background image of an object - html/css

Tags: html, css

im making my eport folio and have used a gallery from the internet. i didnt make the orignal but ive tweaked it to fit my website and changed it to my liking. On the original, the left and right buttons used an image of arrows but when i change the css to use the arrows from my folder, they wont show and nothing i try works. bare in mind there is alot of code for this gallery so im just going to post the relevant css code and the html code.

it makes no sense because the same code works on the orignal, im not sure if ive changed something and not noticed. before someone says, the file path is correct, i have all my html pages in a folder, then the "Images" folder with them containing all my images, including next.png and prev.png. i can provide screenshots, more code, anything that will help, thanks.

Comment: i also forgot to mention, if i put the original images in my folder, it still doesnt work even when using the original code. If there is even a way to just put text in them, i can just put > instead which is fine.

Comment: please provide a fiddle, that way it would be easier to help

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4nke76ye/     is that ok? i had to use random images but the buttons stayed the same in the bottom right

Answer (score 1):

Try uploading your image to a free hosting site and use an absolute file reference instead of a relative.

```
#slide5:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(4) {
    background: url('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/555568875681480704/5Z6shg5R.png') no-repeat;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 -5px;
    display: block;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

Changing the image path worked for me.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/4nke76ye/4/)

Comment: This works but my lecturer said i should only use images in my image file. How would i do that? I tried  "background: url('../Images/next.png') no-repeat;" but that doesnt work even though thats the file path

Comment: background: url() gets really tricky with relative pathing, especially when working locally because each machine has a different directory structure. Try `"background: url('Images/next.png') no-repeat;"`

Answer (score 1):

You do not have the buttons that they used in their example, but fortunatley you can use any buttons you would like! You can trying going back to the source and looking for them if that's what you prefer or you can create/find your own.I just put random arrows in for now. I also inserted comments where you will put your new arrow images once you find them. Hope it helps!

Here is an updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/4nke76ye/2/

```css
#cc-slider {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 850px;
 width:500px;
 position: absolute;
 left:45%;
 padding-bottom:30px;
}

#cc-slider input {
 display: none;
}


#slide1:checked ~ #cc-slides .inner { margin-left:0; }
#slide2:checked ~ #cc-slides .inner { margin-left:-100%; }
#slide3:checked ~ #cc-slides .inner { margin-left:-200%; }
#slide4:checked ~ #cc-slides .inner { margin-left:-300%; }
#slide5:checked ~ #cc-slides .inner { margin-left:-400%; }


#overflow {
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;

}

#cc-slides article img {
 width: 500px;
}

#cc-slides .inner {
 width: 500%;
 line-height: 0;
}

#cc-slides article {
 width: 20%;
 float: left;
}

#controls {
 margin: -8% 0 0 84%;
 width: 15%;
 height: 50px;
}

#controls label { 
 display: none;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 
}

#active {
 margin: 23% 0 0;
 text-align: center;
}

#active label {
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 background: #f89e67;
}

#active label:hover {
 background: #ccc;
 border-color: #777 !important;
}

#controls label:hover {
 opacity: 0.8;
}

#slide1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2), 
#slide2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(3), 
#slide3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(4), 
#slide4:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(5), 
#slide5:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1) {
  /*this is where the next arrow image goes */
 background: url('http://www.hamptoninnbwiairport.com/wp-content/themes/vista/assets/images/next.png') no-repeat;
 float: right;
 margin: 0 0px 0 0;
 display: block;
 background-color:#000;
}


#slide1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(5),
#slide2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1),
#slide3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2),
#slide4:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(3),
#slide5:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(4) {
  /*this is where the previous arrow image goes */
 background: url('http://www.belgers.com/walter/computers/onyx/neat-round.theme/prev.png') no-repeat;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 0 0 -5px;
 display: block;
 background-color:#000;
}



/* cctooltip Box */

.cctooltip {
 
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-top: 560px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.cctooltip h3 {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 margin: 0 0 5px;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-style: normal;
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #222222;
 padding: 5px;
 padding-right:10px;
 font-family: "Tahoma";
}



/* cc-slider Styling */

#cc-slides {
 margin: 45px 0 0;
 
 
 padding: 1%;
 
 background: #000;
 
}


/* Animation */

#cc-slides .inner {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
 -webkit-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
 -moz-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
    -ms-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
     -o-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
        transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); /* easeInOutQuart */

 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
 -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
    -ms-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
     -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); /* easeInOutQuart */
}

#cc-slider {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

#controls label{
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
 -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
 transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
}

#slide1:checked ~ #cc-slides article:nth-child(1) .cctooltip,
#slide2:checked ~ #cc-slides article:nth-child(2) .cctooltip,
#slide3:checked ~ #cc-slides article:nth-child(3) .cctooltip,
#slide4:checked ~ #cc-slides article:nth-child(4) .cctooltip,
#slide5:checked ~ #cc-slides article:nth-child(5) .cctooltip {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out 0.6s;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out 0.6s;
 -o-transition: all 1s ease-out 0.6s;
 transition: all 1s ease-out 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<article id="cc-slider">
  <input checked="checked" name="cc-slider" id="slide1" type="radio">
  <input name="cc-slider" id="slide2" type="radio">
  <input name="cc-slider" id="slide3" type="radio">
  <input name="cc-slider" id="slide4" type="radio">
  <input name="cc-slider" id="slide5" type="radio">
  <div id="cc-slides">
    <div id="overflow">
      <div class="inner">
        <article>
          <div class="cctooltip">
            <h3>Half adder/ full adder</h3>
          </div>
          <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/555568875681480704/5Z6shg5R.png"> 
        </article>
        <article>
          <div class="cctooltip">
            <h3>Seven segment display</h3>
          </div>
          <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/555568875681480704/5Z6shg5R.png"> </article>
        <article>
          <div class="cctooltip">
            <h3>content</h3>
          </div>
          <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/555568875681480704/5Z6shg5R.png"> </article>
        <article>
          <div class="cctooltip">
            <h3>content</h3>
          </div>
          <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/555568875681480704/5Z6shg5R.png"> </article>
        <article>
          <div class="cctooltip">
            <h3>content</h3>
          </div>
          <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/555568875681480704/5Z6shg5R.png"> </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="controls">
    <label for="slide1"></label>
    <label for="slide2"></label>
    <label for="slide3"></label>
    <label for="slide4"></label>
    <label for="slide5"></label>
  </div>
</article>
```

Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: This works but my lecturer said i should only use images in my image file. How would i do that? I tried  "background: url('../Images/next.png') no-repeat;" but that doesnt work even though thats the file path

Comment: create a folder in your web folder named 'Images' and then put the images inside of that. Name your image 'next.png' and the current url should access with no problems

Comment: im not sure what that means, please explain

Answer (score 0):

i did it. i just replaced

```
background: url('../Images/Next.png') no-repeat;
```

with

```
background: url("Images/Next.png"); no-repeat;
```

thanks for the help everyone

Comment: You beat me to it by 19 seconds.   Glad you were able to solve it.